# Can a JPA entity have multiple OneToMany associations?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

Adding two `OneToMany` associations to my entity class seems not to work. It works fine if I remove one of them.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "school")
public class School {

    private List<Teacher> teachers;
    private List<Student> students;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "school", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Teacher> getTeachers()
        return this.teachers;
    }
    public void setTeachers(List<Teacher> teachers) {
         this.teachers = teachers;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "school", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Student> getStudents()
        return this.students;
    }
    public void setStudents(List<Student> teachers) {
         this.students = students;
    }
}
```

Then in `Teacher` and `Student` I have the correct `ManyToOne` annotations

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher {
    private School school;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "school_id")
    public School getSchool() {
        return this.school;
    }
    public void setSchool(School school) {
        this.school = school;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    private School school;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "school_id")
    public School getSchool() {
        return this.school;
    }
    public void setSchool(School school) {
        this.school = school;
    }
}
```

I also have `id` fields with the correct annotations (`@Id`, `@GeneratedValue`)

So to me it seems like I cannot have more than one `@OneToMany` in the same class. Is this correct?

Comment: No, it's not correct at all. You can have as many of them as you want. What do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: might be a problem with both relationships having the same name?

Comment: Nothing gets returned from the database when I'm retrieving a user. There is no stacktrace, not even a warning. I can see that hibernate is mapping all classes

Comment: @Jens the variable is called `school` in both classes so they have to have the same `mappedBy` value, don't they?

Comment: so what sql statement is hibernate executing?

Comment: It's just a simple select statement from an unrelated table called user. It gets the user by the email address. HQL is something like `from user where email="..."`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Why FetchType.EAGER is a bad idea

You can have multiple one-to-many associations, as long as only one is EAGER.

But, even if you can use `Set` instead of `List` to bypass this [`MultipleBagFetchException`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/), it's not a good thing to do because you'll end up with a Cartesian Product.

### Avoiding the Cartesian Product

The best thing to do is to NOT use EAGER at all. You should use `LAZY` for all associations and eager fetch multiple `many-to-one` and `one-to-one` associations and at most one `one-to-many` association using the JOIN FETCH JPQL directive.

If you want to fetch multiple `one-to-many` associations, you can use the `Hibernate.initialize(proxy)` method for the 2nd or 3rd association.

### Fetching multiple parents along with multiple child collections

However, if you have a collection of parent entities that need to load multiple child associations, then you can use `JOIN FETCH` for the first collection since, if you try to eagerly fetch multiple child collections, then you'll end up with a Cartesian Product.

SO, assuming you wanted to fetch multiple `Post` parent entities along with their `comments` and `tags` collections, you can fetch the `comments` in the first query:

```
List<Post> _posts = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select distinct p " +
    "from Post p " +
    "left join fetch p.comments " +
    "where p.id between :minId and :maxId ", Post.class)
.setParameter("minId", 1L)
.setParameter("maxId", 50L)
.setHint(QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
.getResultList();
```

And, for the second `tags` collection, you can issue the following secondary query:

```
_posts = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select distinct p " +
    "from Post p " +
    "left join fetch p.tags t " +
    "where p in :posts ", Post.class)
.setParameter("posts", _posts)
.setHint(QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
.getResultList();
```

How does this work?

The first query fetches the `Post` entities which are attached to the current `EntityManager`. The `comments` collection is fetched for each `Post` entity, but the `tags` collection is represented by a Proxy.

The second query will fetch the `tags`, but since Hibernate already cached the `Post` entities, it will just replace the `tags` Proxy collections with the actual `tags` entries fetched from the database.

Comment: I'm going to try that later today and accept your answer if it works. Thanks in advance, I've been having a problem with for a while

Comment: What if one of **OneToMany** is removed for **Just @ManyToOne** with the same name in the both **owning sides**?

Comment: This has worked for me, but only with using a @Transactional annotation for the method that fetches the parent objecst. Do you think this hints to me having another hidden issue or is that normal?

Comment: @FlorianBaierl If you don't have `@Transactional` in the service that called the repository in question, you are having a hidden issue, yes.

Comment: Okay, so having to add Transactional is normal. Alright, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think your @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn annotations should be put on the private school property of both type Teacher and Student. I noticed you have it on the public getter methods in both of them.